# Identifying which lines cross building polygons using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, intersection, select-by-location

I have the following lines generated from coordinates with XY to Line. I would like to select and delete the lines which cross and are contained within the buildings. I need to do this to find the distance between buildings. I have tried using the select by attribute tool with no luck so far. Also due to the high number of lines Arcmap 10.3 tends to crash a lot.

[image]

Comment: Do you have access to the Advanced license, you can run the erase tool. Which will remove all features crossing the buildings.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure the lines and polygons are in a geodatabase to improve performance.

Start Editing.

If you want to **delete the entire line** just "select by location" and use intersect to select lines that intersect buildings and then delete them.

Leave for a while, come back.

Save edits.

If you want to just **delete the part of the lines** that pass through the buildings.

Use the [ERASE](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/erase.htm) tool it will do it in one step.

No Info license?

[Add a field](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/add-field.htm) to the buildings name DELETE (short integer) and add the value 1 to all buildings.

Run the [Identity](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/310468/identifying-which-lines-cross-building-polygons-using-arcmap) tool (join_attributes = ALL)

Delete the lines that have the attribute DELETE = 1

Answer (score -3):

Check what file format you are using.

its file format must be able to store the topological properties of the objects.  From this you can query in a database console and question the spatial relationships between your objects like: cross, touch, overlap, etc. If you are using Arcmap, the ESRI .shp format does not allow this as far as I know.

A good tip is to look at topological rules of geographic objects. ArcGIS can do this using the GDB / ESRI format.